# OLE DB ORA-01008: not all variables bound (but they are)

Tags: c#, oledb

I am trying to talk to an application which runs a very old version of Oracle (8). I need to do a query first to get the most recent id then insert using this id. Unfortunately I get an error on execution. I have trawled the web but I can't find anyone using this sort of Query, so any help pointers would be appreciated.

```
private static OleDbConnection GetConn()
{
return new OleDbConnection()
{
    ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString
    };
}

public bool AddModel(Model model)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = GetConn();
    conn.Open();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("DECLARE max_id INTEGER; ");
    sb.Append("BEGIN ");
    sb.Append("SELECT MAX(SORTID) into max_id FROM QRY.TABLE where status = 'A'; ");
    sb.Append("max_id := max_id + 1; ");
    sb.Append("INSERT INTO QRY.TABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,SORTID) VALUES(? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,max_id);");
    sb.Append("END;");
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sb.ToString(), conn))
{
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("COL1", model.ID);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("COL2", model.Description);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("COL3", model.Perc);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("COL4", model.Amount);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("COL5", model.Status);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("COL6", model.UpdatedUser);
    command.Parameters.Add("COL7", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

NB I had to reformat the code in this post to remove any references to real tables so it might have put in some typeos. The real code does compile and run.

Comment: It looks fine to me so are you sure you are passing the correct data types and that no null values are causing problems?

Comment: It looks alreight to me too, unfortunately it doesn't work. There are no nulls, I have tried hard coding the values. The insert statement works it I run it on its own. I guess OLE DB just cant do this type of query.

Comment: Oracel isn't my strong point but from what i have seen (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01008_plsql_variables_bound.htm) the max_id needs a : in front of it in the insert stantment.  I don't have an Oracel box to test it so please let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried adding the : before maxid still got the not all variables bound error.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify

```
 sb.Append("INSERT INTO QRY.TABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,SORTID) VALUES(@COL1,@COL2,@COL3,@COL4,@COL5,@COL6,@COL7,max_id);");
```

And modify this

```
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COL1", model.ID);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COL2", model.Description);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COL3", model.Perc);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COL4", model.Amount);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COL5", model.Status);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COL6", model.UpdatedUser);
    command.Parameters.Add("@COL7", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't actually answer my question

Comment: It also doesnt work at all with OleDb provider for Oracle. The bind variable should be a question mark "?".

Comment: You can read this article sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Or maybe the more recent version where ? is used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Cookie yes it's possible different version